# regsvr32.exe throws ASSERT_ERROR with hInstance

Tags: c++, directshow, assert

I try to register a custom filter for DirectShow but windows won't register it correctly.

When I run  a "ASSERT Failed" box shows up telling me:

```
g_hInst is NULL at Line 388 in file "dllsetup.cpp"
```

The file is located in the Microft SKD directory in the usual samples..\dshow\baseclasses folder. When pressing "Yes" the regsvr32.exe returns successfully.

I checked the registry entry with regedit and the file path in InProcServer32 **is set to the directory of** regsvr32.exe itself. (which confirms the missing HINSTANCE). DllRegisterServer needs a valid DLL-instance but cant get it...but WHY?

I am stuck because of this wrong registy entry the filter cannot be added to any filter graph (error message: Error in DLL --> which means it calls regsvr32.exe to "find the filter")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From include/BaseClasses/dllsetup.cpp:

```
// g_hInst handle is set in our dll entry point. Make sure
// DllEntryPoint in dllentry.cpp is called
ASSERT(g_hInst != 0);
```

Not a lot of possible failure modes, the comment is pretty explicit.  You probably simply forgot to call DllEntryPoint() in your DllMain() function.  Which is called as soon as regsvr32.exe loads the DLL.  Use the debugger in case of doubt.  Project + Properties, Debugging, set the Command to c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe and set a breakpoint on your DllMain() function.  Press F5.

Comment: I am still a newbie to direct show filter but do I have to explicetely implement a DllMain function? I thought DirectShow handles "DllMain, DllCanUnloadNow, DllGetClassObject" on its own and all I have to do was defining them in a .def-file.

Comment: Solved issues by calling DllEntryPoint and resetting my project setup after reading MSDN documentation on DShow-filters --> [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). **Having the same problem???: Look at this site:[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: Interesting that that link explicitly contradicts the information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375485(v=vs.85).aspx that suggests (a) there is no need to implement a DllMain as the base classes supply one (although it talks about it using a different name but doesn't describe how this works) and (b) the dll entry function (i.e. DllMain) shouldn't be exported,  MS need to get their documentation together on this...